# Relay a service outside of firewall securely using WCF and X?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, security

I have a WCF service inside the firewall that I want to expose on a semi-public net in a secure manner. A few limitations:

- I can't use Azure and [relay services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/) as I'm still not the internet - just on more public net.
- I only want to open the firewall between the internal one and the more public one for *outgoing traffic* (this is a requirement) - but I still want to be able to communicate request response pattern.
- I need this to be fairly fast and like to avoid persisting the message onto disk etc.

The scenario is today solved by using a semi-public service and then have [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) saving the message, the internal service then has an open connection to HornetQ to receive the message. The response is then published on a separate HornetQ queue and finally the response sent by the semi-public service.

How can something similar be solved using Microsoft techniques and WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) or [BasicHttpsBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpsbinding.aspx) and a [Duplex (two way) contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184.aspx). Note that you don't *have* to use a Http binding, however these go over ports that are frequently unblocked by default meaning you won't have to punch any more holes in any firewalls.

Comment: Ok, great, you don't have a link or anything else that could give some more information on how do this works?

Comment: @Riri No - this can get quite large and quite complex very quickly depending on what you want to do. You might turn up some simple examples on Code Project, I would suggest you read the MSDN docs, then create a couple of simple services just to get the hang of it. Once you've got it nailed you can start to apply your real service contract.